# Javascript: move objects from one array to another: Best approach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays, called 'objects' and 'appliedObjects'.  I'm trying to come up with an elegant way in Javascript and/or Angular to move objects from one array to another.

Initially I did something like this:

```
   $scope.remove = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.appliedObjects, function (element, index) {
            if (element.selected) {
                element.selected = false;
                $scope.objects.push(element);
                $scope.appliedObjects.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    }

   $scope.add= function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.objects, function (element, index) {
            if (element.selected) {
                element.selected = false;
                $scope.appliedObjects.push(element);
                $scope.objects.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

But then I realized that when the value was removed from the looping array, and it would not add or remove every other item, since it went by index.

Then I tried using a temporary array to hold the list of items to be added or removed, and I started getting strange referential issues.

I'm starting to spin a bit on what the best solution to this problem would be...any help and/or guidance would much appreciated.

Comment: If objects and appliedObjects are arrays, then the parameters in the forEach callback function should be `function (element, index) {...}`, or in your case element could be object

Comment: @micnil Thanks I'll update the code.

Comment: Is key a value of the object or an indece? If not is there a property of the object that is an unique identifier?

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I just updated it...changed 'key' to 'index'.  It is in fact the index of the array.

Comment: No unique identifier property? If there is I think I have a solution that will work.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 There is a unique ID property within the element, yes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function moveElements(source, target, moveCheck) {
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        var element = source[i];
        if (moveCheck(element)) {
            source.splice(i, 1);
            target.push(element);
            i--;
        }
    } 
}

function selectionMoveCheck(element) {
   if (element.selected) {
       element.selected = false;
       return true;
   }
}

$scope.remove = function () {
    moveElements($scope.appliedObjects, $scope.objects, selectionMoveCheck);
}

$scope.add = function () {
    moveElements($scope.objects, $scope.appliedObjects, selectionMoveCheck);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the selectionMoveCheck param?

Comment: @morganpdx, it is callback function that should return true for elements to move.

Comment: Oh right I see it now...isn't there a typo however in the function name?  Shouldn't it be moveCheck(element)?

Comment: `moveCheck` is a param of `moveElements`, `selectionMoveCheck` is specific function passed as param. Of course you can remove `moveCheck` and call `selectionMoveCheck` directly. I add param for greater flexibility.

Comment: I removed the moveCheck param and used selectionMoveCheck directly, and got it working...thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When a construct does too much automatically (like forEach, or even a for-loop, in this case), use a more primitive construct that allows you to say what should happen clearly, without need to work around the construct.  Using a while loop, you can express what needs to happen without resorting to backing up or otherwise applying workarounds:

```
function moveSelected(src, dest)  {
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < src.length ) {
        var item = src[i];
        if (item.selected) {
            src.splice(i,1);
            dest.push(item);
        }
        else i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to move simply whole array you could do:

```
appliedObjects = objects;
objects = []
```

Of course it won't work if they were parameters of a function!
Otherwise I cannot see other way than copying in the loop, e.g.

```
while (objects.length) {
    appliedObjects.push(objects[0]);
    objects.splice(0,1);
}
```

or if you like short code :) :

```
while (objects.length) appliedObjects.push(objects.splice(0,1));
```

check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/060ywajm/

Answer (score 2):

You are altering the array while iterating on it, you will always miss some elements.

One way of doing it would be to use a third array to store the references of the objects that need to be removed from the array:

```
// "$scope.add" case
var objectsToRemove = [];

$scope.objects.forEach(function (value) {
  if (value.selected) {
    value.selected = false;
    $scope.appliedObjects.push(value);
    objectsToRemove.push(value);
  }
});

objectsToRemove.forEach(function (value) {
  $scope.objects.splice($scope.objects.indexOf(value), 1);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but started getting reference errors; there is a checkbox associated with each object, and when I tried using a temp storage array for some reason the same objects existed in both arrays and when you click the checkbox next to one of them, the other one was selected as well.  Very odd.

Comment: I'll give this another go however with your solution and see how it fairs.

Comment: Yeah same issue.  It adds it to the new array, but doesn't remove it from the originating array, and in the display if you click on the checkbox next to the one that was added, the original one's checkbox gets checked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now this maybe is not a fair answer, but if you notice you are doing alot of complicated object/array manipulations, you should really check out lodash or underscore library. then you could solve this with on liner:

```
//lodash remove function
appliedObjects.push.apply( appliedObjects, _.remove(objects, { 'selected': true}));

//or if you want to insert in the beginning of the list:
appliedObjects.splice(0, 0, _.remove(objects, { 'selected': true}));
```

Comment: Well it's always good to know what libraries are out there to make my life easier :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a first pass at what I think will work for you. I'm in the process of making a test page so that I can test the accuracy of the work and will update the tweaked result, which hopefully there will not be.

EDIT: I ran it and it seems to do what you are wanting if I understand the problem correctly. There were a couple of syntax errors that I edited out.

Here's the plunk with the condensed, cleaned code http://plnkr.co/edit/K7XuMu?p=preview

HTML

```
<button ng-click="transferArrays(objects, appliedObjects)">Add</button>
<button ng-click="transferArrays(appliedObjects, objects)">Remove</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.transferArrays = function (arrayFrom, arrayTo) {
var selectedElements;
selectedElements = [];
angular.forEach(arrayFrom, function(element) {
  if (element.isSelected) {
    element.isSelected = false;
    selectedElements.push(element);
  }
});
angular.forEach(selectedElements, function(element) {
  arrayTo.push(arrayFrom.splice(
    arrayFrom.map(function(x) {
      return x.uniqueId;
    })
    .indexOf(element.uniqueId), 1));
});
};
```

Old code

```
$scope.remove = function () {
        var selectedElements;
        selectedElements = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.appliedObjects, function (element) {
            if (element.isSelected) {
                element.isSelected = false;
                selectedElements.push(element);
            }
        });
        angular.forEach(selectedElements, function (element) {
            $scope.objects.push($scope.appliedObjects.splice(
                $scope.appliedObjects.map(function  (x) { return x.uniqueId; })
                .indexOf(element.uniqueId), 1));
        });
    };

$scope.add = function () {
        var selectedElements;
        selectedElements = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.objects, function (element) {
            if (element.isSelected) {
                element.isSelected = false;
                selectedElements.push(element);
            }
        });
        angular.forEach(selectedElements, function (element) {
            $scope.appliedObjects.push($scope.objects.splice(
                $scope.objects.map(function  (x) { return x.uniqueId; })
                .indexOf(element.uniqueId), 1));
        });
    };
```

Comment: There's a couple parentheses missing at the end of the indexOf lines.  So far it's not working...the selectedElements array doesn't seem to get updated

Comment: I'm working on a Plunkr but I always have trouble getting them going for some reason. I'll post when it's up.

Comment: @morganpdx here is a working plunk, I may have made an incorrect assumption about your data though http://plnkr.co/edit/K7XuMu?p=preview

Comment: Cool! I'll check it out in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this oneliner as many times as many items you need to move from arr1 to arr2 just prepare check func

```
arr2.push(arr1.splice(arr1.findIndex(arr1El => check(arr1El)),1)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to concat 2 arrays:

```js
let array3 = [...array1, ...array2];
```