# each function check if iterated through all items then start over

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('li.cont').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i + 1) * 3000).fadeOut(1500);
```

I want to add the ability to check if all my `li.cont` have been iterated through and then if so, start over. As opposed to current functionality where the final item fades Out and then the area is just blank.

Comment: Why not just put a loop around that each?

Comment: now also jquery 3.1 problem ?

Comment: I think your looking for infinite loop, right?

Comment: What do you mean with "start over" when fading out again will have no effect if you have nothing visible anymore?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?  like an infinitely fadein/fadeout effect?  if so a css transition with steps would be a better approach

Comment: put your entire construct in loop and set end value for counter var to count    of items obtained by $('li.cont')  when counter var reaches the final value set it to initial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the callback argument of `fadeOut`, which gets called when one animation is finished. There you would start the next in a round-robin way. Once you get at the first again, you just restore the situation and show all elements.

```js
var $items = $('li.cont');
(function loop(i) {
    if (!i) $items.show(); // starting from scratch: show all
    $items.eq(i).fadeToggle(1500, loop.bind(null, (i+1)%$items.length));
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="cont">A</li>
<li class="cont">B</li>
<li class="cont">C</li>
</ul>
```

I have in fact used `fadeToggle`, which comes down to the same thing, except that it allows me to demo another variant. This one does *not* reset the situation after all elements have been hidden, and so the toggle will start to fade each item in instead of out. Then when that is done, the fading direction is reversed again:

```js
var $items = $('li.cont');
(function loop(i) {
    $items.eq(i).fadeToggle(1500, loop.bind(null, (i+1)%$items.length));
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="cont">A</li>
<li class="cont">B</li>
<li class="cont">C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a copy of the object and adding it to a secondary array and then back?  I do this with angular when making slide shows. I start at the end of the array and work my way to 0.

```
var a = [];
var b = [];

function changeIn(){
     var l = a.length
     if(a.length === 0)
     {
          angular.copy(b, a);
     }

     // do stuff here
     var x = []
     angular.copy(a[l], x);
     b.push(x);
     if (l > -1) {
         array.splice(l, 1);
     }
};
```

alternatively you can use array.pop() or array.shift() to get the values of the either the last or first item and remove it from the list as well.  The code I am showing in this example is definitely the longest way of doing this. There are many examples found on Stack for doing this more efficiently depending on how you would like to go about writing the code.

There is a pretty good sample found here:

[Javascript: move objects from one array to another: Best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887967/javascript-move-objects-from-one-array-to-another-best-approach)

Comment: how does this have anything to do with the question?