# how to hide elements that are in both arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one stores data,

```
 (Langs = ['C', 'PHP', 'Python', 'Basic'])
```

the second will be filled by clicking on elements from the first array

```
Buttons = []
```

When I click on one of the Langslements, this element goes into the Button array, where it turns into a button.

I want the render method to show only those elements that are not in the Buttons array, but are in the Langs array

```
function render(Data = Langs)
        {
            Out.innerHTML = '';

            if(Data.length)
            {
                Data.forEach((elem) => {
                
                    Out.innerHTML += `<div class="collection-item">
                                        <h5>${elem}</h5>
                                      </div>`
                })

                 addButton();
            }
            else
            {
                Out.innerHTML = '<h3 class="grey-text">Not found</h3>'
            }
            
        }
```

Simply put, when you click on an element, this element is hidden from the user and a button with the same name is created instead.

Comment: There are a number of questions about [how to move elements from one array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31887967/215552). I would expect that doing that, and adding code that generates buttons for elements in the `Buttons` array, would solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help. You can also use [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp#:%7E:text=The%20includes()%20method%20determines,element%2C%20and%20false%20if%20not.)

```js
let Langs = ['C', 'PHP', 'Python', 'Basic'];
let Buttons = ['PHP'];
Langs.forEach(function(lang){
    if(!Buttons.includes(lang)){
        console.log(lang);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an intermediate array based on Langs with elements that are not in Buttons. I suggest you to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const elementsToShow = Langs.filter(l=>!Buttons.includes(l))
```

Comment: You could use `.filter()` with that same logic to get an array containing the elements to display.

Comment: my fault, I was thinking about filter but I wrote map. I edited the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple explanation of how it might work.
Langs as the primary array and Button as the secondary array. Mapping Langs with Button I get a new intermediate array ( newLang ) with result what I want to display.

```
const Langs = ['C', 'PHP', 'Python', 'Basic'];
let Button = ['PHP'];
let newLang = [];
let fillNewLang = Langs.map( x => {
    if ( !Buttons.includes( x ) ) {
        newLang.push( x );
    }
})
console.log( newLang );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it